# How do I purchase an additional inscription slot in Tales of Maj'Eyal?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I know that it costs a category point, which is awarded every 10 levels but I just cannot find the UI element that lets me purchase the additional slot.  How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe the UI has changed since 2012, but there's an "Inscriptions" button on the level up screen which you can press to add another slot (assuming you have a category point available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to a rune/inscription in your inventory and select use on it, it will ask you if you want to get an additional slot.